# What is it about web browser cache design that causes performance to degrade when the cache grows

Tags: browser-cache

The nearly universal advice one gets when describing slow performance or erratic performance in a web browser is "Have you tried to clear the cache?"

Since I've gotten this advice with every browser I've ever used, I assume their cache implementations share things in common.

What is it about large amounts of cached data that degrades performance or even causes browsers to malfunction?

How is browser caching implemented at the data storage and retrieval level?